# how to use Python multimethod with custom class as argument type

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, multimethod, single-dispatch

I have the following classes setup:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    pass
```

Then I have a method that gets called with 2 arguments:

- x -> always a string
- y -> one of the classes above (A, B, or C)
  And we do something different depending on which class was passed as second argument.

```
@multimethod
def click(x: str, y: A=None):
    do_A_thing()

@multimethod
def click(x: str, y: B=None):
    do_B_thing()

@multimethod
def click(x: str, y: object=None):
    raise expeption
```

With this configuration, an exception is always raised even when y is of type A or B.

I also looked at using [singledispatch](https://peps.python.org/pep-0443/), but I need the validation on the second argument and I can't switch their places.
I also tried using [multipledispatch](https://pypi.org/project/multipledispatch/), but it didn't work similarly to multimethod.

Comment: rather than 3 `@multimethod` do you want one followed by 2 `@click.register`?

Comment: can't switch order of arguments, and register only works on first argument

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to the [`doc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). Notice further that the dispatch occurs *"on the type of the first argument"*. So you should refactor the signature of the functions.

Here a minimal working example for a functions *annotated with types*

```
@functools.singledispatch
def click(y:A, x:str):
    print('A')

@click.register
def _(y:B, x:str, ):
    print('B')

@click.register
def _(y:C, x:str):
    print('C')

click(B(), "x")
#B
```

and for a function which *doesn’t use type annotations* you need to pass the appropriate type argument explicitly to the decorator itself

```
@functools.singledispatch
def click(y, x):
    print('A')

@click.register(B)
def _(y, x):
    print('B')

@click.register(C)
def _(y, x):
    print('C')

x = 'str'
click(B(), x)
#B
```

---

For switching the order of the argument it's enough to define a decorator, `arg_swapper`, with this functionality

```
def arg_swapper(func):
    # interchange the order of the args of a function (assuming it takes exactly two parameters!)
    def wrapper(func_arg1, func_arg2):
        return func(func_arg2, func_arg1)
    return wrapper


def do_A_thing(x, y): print(f"do_A_thing({x=},{y=})")
def do_B_thing(x, y): print(f"do_B_thing({x=},{y=})")
def do_C_thing(x, y): print(f"do_C_thing({x=},{y=})")


@functools.singledispatch
@arg_swapper
def click(x, y): do_A_thing(x, y)    

@click.register(B)
@arg_swapper
def _(x, y): do_B_thing(x, y)

@click.register(C)
@arg_swapper
def _(x, y): do_C_thing(x, y)

x = 'str'
click(B(), x)
click(A(), x)
click(C(), x)

# Output
#do_B_thing(x='string',y=<__main__.B object at 0x7f8ef577bd10>)
#do_A_thing(x='string',y=<__main__.A object at 0x7f8ef577bd10>)
#do_C_thing(x='string',y=<__main__.C object at 0x7f8ef577bd10>)
```

Notice that you either *stack* the decorators (as shown above) or do an explicit call

```
@click.register(C)
def _(x, y): arg_swapper(do_C_thing)(x, y)
```

Comment: I can't switch the order of the arguments. Which is why instead of register, I'm using multimethod/multipledispatch

Comment: @KSS The syntax of `singledispatch` is a bit limited, would be easier to make a single function with a `if/elif/else` "dispatcher"?

Comment: @KSS I think that the decorator is not even needed, just `def click(x, y): do_A_thing(y, x)`. I am a bit confused... so tell me if my edit make sense